# Prove that a matrix is diagonalizable, transformation R3->P2

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a question regarding an old exam I was going through.

Let $p(x) = x^3-6x^2+11x-6$. $A$ is an $n$ x $n$ matrix with the property
$p(A) = 0$ (Null matrix)

Show that $A$ is diagonalizable.

Example: If $f(x) = x^2+2x+1$ then $f(A) = A^2+2A+I$ where $I$ is the 
identity matrix.

The solution(which I do not understand) is the following:

factorization gives: 
$p(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$

Contemplate the transformation $S: R3 \to P2$ given by:
$$(a,b,c)^T \to a(x-1)(x-2)+b(x-1)(x-3)+c(x-2)(x-3)$$

We can "easily" see that the kernel $ker(S) = 0$ by evaluating the image of $S$ in the points $1,2,3$.
Therefore $S$ is surjective and we can find $a,b,c$ such that
$$a(x-1)(x-2)+b(x-1)(x-3)+c(x-2)(x-3) = 1$$

we can write this as:
$$v=1*v=Iv=a(A-I)(A-2I)v+b(A-I)(A-3I)v+c(A-2I)(A-3I)v =v_1+v_2+v_3$$

since $p(A) = 0$ we see that $(A-3I)v_1=(A-2I)v_2=(A-I)v_3=0$, therefore $v1,v2,v3$ are eigenvectors to $A$. Therefore we have found a basis of eigenvectors to $A$
and a is diagonalizabe.

If this is to messy please let me know and I'l use MathJax instead
Thanks beforehand for any tips or explanations regarding this problem

This section is what bothers me, how did they come up with this transformation? And why?
"Contemplate the transformation $S: R3 \to P2$ given by:
$$(a,b,c)^T \to a(x-1)(x-2)+b(x-1)(x-3)+c(x-2)(x-3)$$"

Comment: what's your problem? What do you not understand?

Comment: Thanks for taking your time! Greatly appreciated.
First: The transformation S:R3->P2, how did they decide that it's given
by a(x-1)..+c(x-2)(x-3)
And why is S surjective? Because ker(S)=0?

Comment: They are defining $S$ as that specific map. It is a linear map between two vectorial spacces of the same dimension, and it is injective, so it is also surjective

Comment: Alright but how? Were did they get it from? It's not in the question, seems to me they just define a random mapping from R3 to P2?

Comment: yes, they're defining it right there. Obviously there's a reason they define exactly that map, but it's not that simple

Comment: If you take the derivative of (x-3)(x-2)(x-1) you get 3x^2-12x+11
which is the same as (x-1)(x-2)+(x-1)(x-3)+(x-2)(x-3)
Any correlation here?

Comment: The given solution seems like a rather roundabout way to prove diagonalizability. Although not directly relevant to your question, it seems that it would be much simpler to observe that $p$ must be $A$’s minimal polynomial.

Comment: It looks to me that what’s going on in the solution is that they’re indirectly constructing a set of projections onto the three eigenspaces of $A$ and then showing that they span the image of $A$. If you work backwards from the expansion of $v$ in terms of these projections, the choice of $S$ isn’t quite so mysterious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the comments addressed your initial question fairly well, so I'd like to present an alternate approach that I feel is more applicable and more in the spirit of many linear algebra proofs. The main fact that we need is:

> $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if the minimal polynomial of $A$ splits as a product of distinct linear factors.

$m(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of the matrix $A$ if it is monic (leading coefficient is $1$) and $m(x)$ is the non-zero polynomial of least degree for which $m(A) = 0$. It is not hard to prove that this implies that $m(x)$ divides any polynomial $f(x)$ for which $f(A) = 0$.

Now in this example, $p(A) = 0$ and $p(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ splits into distinct linear factors. The minimal polynomial of $A$ must divide $p(x)$ and hence also splits into distinct linear factors. Therefore $A$ is diagonalizable.